# Do PHP opcode cache work with __autoload?

Tags: php, autoload, opcode-cache

Sorry if this is basic, I am trying to learn as much as I can about OO in PHP and I am slowly learning how to use it (very limited).

So I am wanting to know if __autoload() has any affect on PHP opcode cache's?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*(Disclaimer : I only know APC)*

What an opcode cache do is :

- when a file is included/required, it take the full path to that file
- check if the opcodes corresponding to that file are already in RAM (in opcode cache)

  - if yes, return those opcode so they are executed
  - if no, load the file and compile it to opcodes ; and store opcodes in cache.

The important point, here, is the entry point : the full path to the file.

What autoloading generally do is :

- get the name of a class
- transform it to the name of a file
- include/require that file

So, the informations that are relevant for the opcode cache (full path to the file, and the fact that it is included/required) are still here.

In consequence, autoload shouldn't bring any trouble with op code caching.

*(And, when using APC, it doesn't, as far as I can tell)*

Comment: This is my experience as well - Opcode caching is not affected by use of autoload

Answer (score 27):

Opcode caches work (or at least should work) with autoloading but you can potentially take a performance hit from.

From [Remember: be nice to byte code caches](http://pooteeweet.org/blog/538):

```
<arnaud_> does autoload have a performance impact when using apc ?
<Rasmus_> it is slow both with and without apc
<Rasmus_> but yes, moreso with apc because anything that is autoloaded is pushed down into the executor
<Rasmus_> so nothing can be cached
<Rasmus_> the script itself is cached of course, but no functions or classes
<Rasmus_> Well, there is no way around that
<Rasmus_> autoload is runtime dependent
<Rasmus_> we have no idea if any autoloaded class should be loaded until the script is executed
<Rasmus_> top-level clean deps would speed things up a lot
<Rasmus_> it's not just autoload
<Rasmus_> it is any sort of class or function declaration that depends on some runtime context
<Rasmus_> if(cond) function foo...
<Rasmus_> if(cond) include file
<Rasmus_> where file has functions and classes 
<Rasmus_> or heaven forbid: function foo() { class bar { } }
```

and [this mail from Ramus](http://marc.info/?l=pecl-dev&m=116512075914909&w=2):

> To clarify, of course conditionally
>   included files get compiled and
>   cached.  The issue is not the included
>   files but the resulting conditionally
>   defined classes and functions needing
>   to be redefined on every request. 
>   Whether that is significant or not
>   comes down to the specifics of the
>   situation, but there is no doubt that
>   it is slower.  It comes down to a NOP
>   vs. a FETCH_CLASS, for example and the
>   NOP is obviously way faster.

Comment: Not sure why this hasn't been upvoted.  I just started a new post regarding this issue as I'd like to know if there are alternative solutions to spl_autoload_register -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1941541/php5-frameworks-autoloading-and-opcode-caching