# PHP5 Frameworks: Autoloading and Opcode Caching

Tags: php, frameworks, autoload, opcode-cache

A number of frameworks utilize `spl_autoload_register()` for dynamically loading classes (i.e. controllers and models).  There are a couple of posts on the issue of autoloading and opcode caching.  One post in particular has a response by @cletus which references @Rasmus making a number of statements which prove to be unsavoury for those utilizing APC as an opcode cache:

- [Do PHP opcode cache work with __autoload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396501/do-php-opcode-cache-work-with-autoload)

There does not appear to be any discussion as to any possible alternatives to autoloading which do not affect opcode cache performance.

**Is there a way to get around the fact autoloaded classes do not get added to the byte code cache?**

*If not, are there any alternative methods for dynamically loading classes which will get cached?*

Comment: from what I recall of my days of Mediawiki + APC, auto-loaded classes will get cached by APC.

Comment: @jldupont - I just updated to reference a specific response that intrigued me to write this post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There seems to still be confusion about this topic, however in most cases it comes down to ease vs performance.

A good mailing list thread to read would be this one on Zend Frameworks mailing list:

http://n4.nabble.com/ZF-and-Autoloading-td640085i20.html

> Now, the correlation is here because if you inherit from not-yet-defined 
>   class, you might rely on autoload to define it (though you might also 
>   rely on include), and actually the presence of the autoload facility may 
>   encourage you to use such inheritance. But this is not the autoload 
>   which brings trouble (see after Ramus' "it's not just autoload" in the 
>   blog for some examples of troublesome things). 
>   So the right phrase would be "people which tend to rely on autoload tend 
>   also to use code which defies compile-time binding". Which can't be seen 
>   as autoload fault, of course, and just avoiding autoload won't help a 
>   bit with that - you would also have to rewrite your code so that 
>   compile-time binding could happen. And it has nothing to do with uses of 
>   autoload with "new", for example.
>
> As for the slowdown from the effects described above - i.e., absence of 
>   the compile-time binding - the code indeed becomes a bit slower and such 
>   code can lead in some obscure cases to some trouble to opcode caches 
>   (not in the autoload cases - but in cases where classes are defined 
>   inside conditions, or, God forbid, different definition is created 
>   depending on condition) - but it has next to nothing to do with using 
>   autoload by itself. 
>   The amount of slowdown, however, seem to be greatly exagerrated by 
>   people - it is nothing (and I repeat to be clear - *NOTHING*) compared 
>   to the performance benefit given by the opcode cache due to the absence 
>   of the disk operations and compilation stage. You could probably 
>   compose an artificial benchmark that would show some significant 
>   slowdown, but I do not believe any real application would even notice.
>
> **source:** http://n4.nabble.com/ZF-and-Autoloading-td640085i20.html#a640092

Comment: [updated link](http://osdir.com/ml/php.zend.framework.general/2007-01/msg00132.html) to the full quote.